# TripleDES Encryption in C#

Tags: .net, encryption

I'm trying TripleDES Encryption with ECB mode. My code looks like that:

```
public static string EncryptDES(string InputText)
        {
            byte[] key = new byte[] { 0x41, 0x42, 0x43, 0x44, 0x45, 0x46, 0x47, 0x48, 0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x34, 0x35, 0x36, 0x37, 0x38, 0x41, 0x42, 0x43, 0x44, 0x45, 0x46, 0x47, 0x48 };
            byte[] clearData = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(InputText);
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            TripleDES alg = TripleDES.Create();
            alg.Key = key;
            alg.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
            CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, alg.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
            cs.Write(clearData, 0, clearData.Length);
            cs.FlushFinalBlock();
            byte[] CipherBytes = ms.ToArray();
            ms.Close();
            cs.Close();
            string EncryptedData = Convert.ToBase64String(CipherBytes);
            return EncryptedData;

        }
```

When I run a test I got an exception that the "Length of Data to decrypt is invalid."

Does anyone knows what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

### Update

My bad !
I found my problem
Instead of using `alg.CreateEncryptor()` I was using `alg.CreateDecyptor()`.

A copy paste issue. :(

Thanks for help, guys

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My bad !
I found my problem
Instead of using `alg.CreateEncryptor()` I was using `alg.CreateDecyptor()`.

A copy paste issue. :(

Thanks for help, guys

Comment: Heh good catch.. I skipped right over that, glad you fixed your issue!

Comment: Thanks CQ for your help. Actually, your suggestion inspired me to find the problem.

Comment: I'm using your algorithm but getting an error when trying to decrypt: invalid size 79 in the line: cs.FlushFinalBlock();
Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your encryption method is using a different key/salt combo than the decryption method and it can't decrypt the data.

During debugging it might be benefical to convert your key & salt to readable strings and waste the cycle's converting them to bytes.. at least for readability.

Answer (score 0):

This could be an encoding problem.  Make sure it's in UTF-8 or something sane. Maybe something like this:

```
Public Shared DefaultEncoding As Text.Encoding = _System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("Unicode")
```

(Reference: [codeproject.com](https://secure.codeproject.com/KB/security/SimpleEncryption.aspx?display=PrintAll&fid=172899&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick&select=1463997&fr=51#xx1463997xx))